# Not able to get any results on using bucket aggregations

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I have some PR data in my ES. This is how the documents are modelled

```
 {
          "Author" : "dheerajrav",
          "Date" : "2012-10-05T10:16:49Z",
          "Number" : 2554441,
          "IsMerged" : false,
          "MergedBy" : "",
          "Body" : ""
        },
        {
          "Author" : "dheerajrav",
          "Date" : "2012-10-05T09:11:35Z",
          "Number" : 2553883,
          "IsMerged" : false,
          "MergedBy" : "",
          "Body" : ""
        },
        {
          "Author" : "crodjer",
          "Date" : "2012-10-04T15:40:22Z",
          "Number" : 2544540,
          "IsMerged" : false,
          "MergedBy" : "",
          "Body" : ""
        },
        {
          "Author" : "crodjer",
          "Date" : "2012-10-04T07:52:20Z",
          "Number" : 2539410,
          "IsMerged" : false,
          "MergedBy" : "",
          "Body" : ""
        }
      .
      .
      .
      ]
    }
```

I am trying the following terms agg on my index but I get no results

```
curl -X GET "localhost:9200/newidx/_search?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'               
{
"aggs" : {
    "contributors" : {
        "terms" : {
            "field" : "Author",
            "size" : 100
        }
    }
  }
}
'
```

The desired result would have been separate buckets for each PR author. This is the response

```
 "aggregations" : {
 "contributors" : {
  "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
  "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
  "buckets" : [ ]
   }
  }
```

Am I modeling my data wrong?

This is the mapping for my index

```
{
  "newidx" : {
   "mappings" : {
     "properties" : {
         "Stats" : {
          "properties" : {
           "Author" : {
             "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
               "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "Body" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "Date" : {
          "type" : "date"
        },
        "IsMerged" : {
          "type" : "boolean"
        },
        "MergedBy" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "Number" : {
          "type" : "long"
           }
         }
       }
     }
    }
 }
}
```

I generate a json file in my code and index it to elasticsearch using elasticsearch_loader, here is the command

`elasticsearch_loader --es-host 'localhost' --index org-skills --type incident json --lines processed.json`

Comment: in your aggregation, use `Author.keyword`. Seems like you have `text` and `keyword` mappings for this field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your mapping:

1. `Author` field is declared as `text` (used for full-text search) and `keyword` (used for matching whole values).

   Read difference between [`text`v/s`keyword`](https://www.elastic.co/blog/strings-are-dead-long-live-strings).
2. The parent mapping name is `Stats`.

You should therefore use `Stats.Author.keyword` in your aggregation query i.e:

```
curl -X GET "localhost:9200/newidx/_search?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'               
{
"aggs" : {
    "contributors" : {
        "terms" : {
            "field" : "Stats.Author.keyword",
            "size" : 100
        }
    }
  }
}
'
```

Answer (score 0):

It needs to be

```
curl -X GET "localhost:9200/newidx/_search?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'               
{
  "aggs" : {
     "contributors" : {
       "terms" : {
         "field" : "Stats.Author.keyword",
         "size" : 100
        }
      }
    }
  }
'
```

Your field Stats.Author is of type text. For the use of aggregations, text-based fields have also to be keyword-fields. Therefore you need to use the field Stats.Author.keyword